# find_all() prints everythigh twice

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started my first Web scraping project and out of some reason when I try to run this simple code, it prints all of the headlines twice.
I have no Idea why and i tried without the for loop, but it still doesnt work.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
 
    website = requests.get("https://www.mlb.com/twins")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "lxml")
    headlines = soup.find_all("li", class_ = "p-headline-stack__headline")

    for headline in headlines:
        headline_text = headline.find("a", "p-headline-stack__link").text
        print(headline_text)
```

this is the output:

'We rake': Twins mash six homers en route to first win
Tap Recap: Buxton, Sánchez, Correa go deep in win ▶️
Injuries & Moves: Stashak injury update
Buxton launches moonshot; bullpen brings Twins back to earth
Twins' No. 29 prospect drives in 9 in HIgh-A debut
Twins rookie gives batters that splinking feeling in debut
28 things to know about 28 Twins
Season Pick ‘Em: Compete to win $100,000!
Twins' Top 30 Prospects list
'We rake': Twins mash six homers en route to first win
Tap Recap: Buxton, Sánchez, Correa go deep in win ▶️
Injuries & Moves: Stashak injury update
Buxton launches moonshot; bullpen brings Twins back to earth
Twins' No. 29 prospect drives in 9 in HIgh-A debut
Twins rookie gives batters that splinking feeling in debut
28 things to know about 28 Twins
Season Pick ‘Em: Compete to win $100,000!
Twins' Top 30 Prospects list

out of some reason it repeats the headlines.
Its probably a simple fix but i am new to programming and cant find the awnser.

Comment: you are printing in a loop.

Comment: if you try without the loop you get the same problem

Comment: You have the text twice in the website

Comment: I checked fo that to and i cant find any other

Comment: @Shost.Op.47 I could... it's not visible twice but it is in the dom. You need to use a more specific locator. `headlines = soup.select("div.l-grid__content--xs-hidden.l-grid__content--sm-hidden li.p-headline-stack__headline")` should do the job.